# showing a element inside input box

Tags: css, angular, input, angular-material

i have a input box created using angular reactive forms

```
<input type="text" formControlName="OrgName" placeholder="Enter name" maxlength="60">
<p  class="fieldRequired" *ngIf="showNameMSg">{{60-profileForm.value.OrgName.length}} characters remaining </p>
```

there is a limit of 60 characters. currently i am showing it on a p tag under the input box.
how can i show the number of remaining characters with some sort of indicator inside the input box.

even if indicator not done.. atleast i must show the remaining numbers of characters available..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this if you want to achieve what you want with the help of CSS-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xmzzf

You will have to provide a parent div with **position as relative** to your input and counter p tag.

The position of p tag will be **absolute** and you can adjust it using CSS (top, right) to get it in the desired position with respect to your input tag.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easy using [Angular Material CDK inputs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples), using the property `suffix`, normally used to set icons, but also can be used to set more info, as you want.

For example, in a phone input:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Telephone</mat-label>
    <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="555-555-1234">
    <div matSuffix>{{counter}}</div>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[image]

You only need to build more rich feedback and that's all. You can test it [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mglnyammyre?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-prefix-suffix-example.html).

Comment: yeah.. it kind of worked.. but it is standing out of the rest of the inputs in my form.. how to disable the material styling.. so that it looks simple textbox with bootstrap class "form-control"

Comment: In this case, you will need work a bit with css as Pooja Mule said, or think if you could need more advanced things and consider use the cdk modifying to your own style. Isn't to difficult.